# Teensy 3.1 Maximum Current Through Ground?

Tags: current, maximum-ratings, teensy

i'm trying to make a usb game controller with 16 buttons and a 2-axis joystick,
and i want to know, what is the maximum current that can go through ground?

I can't find it anywhere, not even the data sheet for the chip (if the answer's there, then tell me the page number).

I don't want to fry my board so this would be very helpful.

This is the diagram :
[image: circuit]

Thanks.

Comment: well, you did not include the chip number nor the datasheet... no crystal balls around here. anyway I suspect that the current is limited by the power supply you will have, that's the USB bus, and you are safe up to 100mA.

Comment: Just search Teensy 3.1 datasheet.

Comment: @Project-i386 I think that's the first time I've seen the OP tell a commenter to read the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the information you're looking for is on page 10 of the datasheet. The max Idd is 185mA and the max current per single digital pin is 25mA.